# Multiple same events fired up on Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

I have a layout **_test.gsp** which contains ***'a click event'*** and that layout is rendered as below.

```
<div id="testid">
    <g:render template="test"/>
</div>
```

And when i click on that _test.gsp layout's event it triggers a single event.

The main page contain ***a button*** which triggers and replaced the above div contain with new ***_test.gsp*** layout on it's click event. But

- After clicking the main page button &
- Click on the _test.gsp event it will fire up two ***click event*** from _test.gsp (looks like instead of replacing the _test.gsp from above div container on the main page button click event, it is added and fired up two events. But i replaced that div and it is replaced out).
- And if i goes on clicking main page button click it will fired up that much of times click event from _test.gsp on the click (2, 3, 4 ... and so on...).

**Question:** what would be the problem of firing up that much events? On the replacement of div container event is not replaced out or what? Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery `on()` or `bind()` in `_test.gsp` to add the event handler for the elements then what's happening is you aren't unbinding the event when you replace the content so it's firing multiple times.

Depending on your needs, you can unbind the event handlers many ways. Either using `off()` with the same selector just before you call `on()` or `bind()` or move your event binding into the main GSP page and bind using `live()`.